# Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'

Tags: azure, powershell, devops

Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'.

After executing below command in Azure powershell task

```
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resourceId -Name $diagnosticsettingname -Enabled $true -Categories $logarray -MetricCategory $metricsarray -WorkspaceId $work
```

I am getting exception as

**"Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'."**

As per the specification there is the -Name parameter in it. So why I am getting this error

Comment: This depends on your version of Azure RM Powershell. The `Name` parameter is listed for version 6.13.0, but not for 5.7.0 and 4.4.1. See [Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/set-azurermdiagnosticsetting)

Comment: Just keep the Note if you are building the CICD pipeline and using the Azure Powershell task, try to use the Older version of i.e. 3. While using Azure powershell latest version It gives exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I think your version of `AzureRM.Insights` module is old, please update the module with:

```
Update-Module -Name AzureRM.Insights -Force
```

And you should note, the `AzureRm` module has been deprecated, it will not be updated anymore, so I recommend you to use the new `Az` module instead of `AzureRm`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0#migrate-existing-scripts-to-az) to migrate to `Az`, then use the command [`Set-AzDiagnosticSetting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-3.6.1).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this, if you want to do both Azure Diagnostics and leveraging an Azure Pipeline to do it, while programmatically doing this at scale with Azure Policy, you can check out this solution which should make this a bit easier to consume.

https://aka.ms/azpolicyPipeline

Without pipeline but automating the policies / policy initiative you can take a look at this project here: https://aka.ms/AzPolicyScripts

I found this post looking for something else related to a bug in Az cmdlets so figured I'd post since I had this detail handy.